# Localized OpenGraph meta information?

Tags: facebook, localization, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

I have a site that is available in multiple languages (English and German for now). The landing page / automatically redirects the visitor to either /en or /de. There are social buttons on the page that however use the / url so that numbers (Facebook like count or Google +1 count) does not segment for different languages.

When sharing a link to the site on Facebook, buttons are configured to share the / page (which also counts as a like since the visitor shares the same url as the like button).
However, if somebody just shares the site url manually, Facebook posts the the English description on his wall, even if the visitor gets the German site.

I guess, Facebook caches OpenGraph information about a site. Is there a way to tell Facebook localized OpenGraph information so that visitors can post links to the site having automatic description in the correct language?

Comment: You can't have multiple OpenGraph info on a single url at the same time. You can force a switch between the english and german version using the facebook linter, but that just refreshes the facebook cache. Nothing stopping you from having two different OpenGraph info on the /en and /de pages of course, and I think that's the best you can do here.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid that this is the only option, but unfortunately this also means that sharing /de and /en would not count up the like button. Too bad.